# Guidance re-writing a question closed as opinion based

Tags: support, closed-questions, opinion-based

I had a question closed as opinion based. I'd like to ask the community if the problem here was the wording I used, that is, how the question was written, of if the subject itself is not suitable to Stack Overflow. I really appreciate any guidance for re-writing it in a way that's acceptable (supposing that the subject is suitable).

This is the problematic question: [Can I ditch CDNs if my page is on GitHub pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76031176/12273078)

Comment: “Is that correct (or a good practice)?” - This question, specifically, requires us to share our opinions if what you describe is “correct” or “good” practice. So the question was properly closed as seeking an opinion.

Comment: @SecurityHound I know that, I'm not disputing it. I just wanted guidance regarding re-writing it.

Comment: Remove any requests that seek our opinion, don’t delete the question, [edit] the question and make it within scope. Routinely deleting questions that could be modified is how users find themselves question banned

Comment: Not all questions belong on Stack Overflow. If you are hitting very specific close reasons, that probably means it is a question that does not belong on Stack Overflow. You have a right and a wrong choice to make. Wrong: try to reword it to cram it on Stack Overflow anyway, and probably see the question downvoted. Or ask it somewhere that supports discussion and mentoring. Use the right tool for the job, and SO is absolutely the wrong tool for discussions, schooling or mentoring.

Comment: Start by thinking about *why* you are asking the question. "Can I do X in Y circumstance" - well, what specifically worries you about doing X, and why do you expect Y to mitigate that concern? What *underlying problem are you trying to solve*? Then, if the question is about the capabilities of some third-party service (like GitHub pages), consider whether it is really a *tech support question for that service*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is "I was told X". Replace that by sources. Also your questions can have several answers, opinion based. Best practices are IMHO in a grey area, opinion based or context based, even though sometimes there could be unanimous. Seeking for advice (what is the best software for X) is also not fitting SO.

I believe it's a duplicate of [Should Github be used as a CDN for javascript libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502540/should-github-be-used-as-a-cdn-for-javascript-libraries), which is also not fitting SO.

I do not think the topic fits SO, even though I could like to see SO quality answers about that topic.